# Turn on text that displays what a button does on long press

Tags: 8.1, lumia-denim

How can I get to see what a particular button would do on long pressing it?

This was earlier working(may be).

I want to see(on long press) a pop up with text that that explains what would happen when I tap that screen space. I cannot find this particular setting in windows phone settings.

Comment: I can't remember Windows Phone ever having such a feature. Did this work in an app or something?

Comment: Are you talking about *any* button, or just those in the app bar at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Yes the ones on the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a long press, but either a slight upward flick, or tapping the eclipses (...) at the right hand edge - this will bring up the textual labels for the round buttons in the app bar.

Comment: Please provide at least two examples. Not within any app but native to the OS. How is this enabled ?

Comment: The Messaging, Phone, People, Mail, Calendar, Music, Photos and Store apps all do this for me (as well as showing other advanced options)

Comment: @user3146086 When you press "checklist" button (more precisely "Select" button), you are able to select multiple conversations to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not a long press, but either a slight upward flick, or tapping the eclipses (...) at the right hand edge - this will bring up the textual labels for the round buttons in the app bar.

Rowland is right, there were no such feature as long press (only in case if you are talking about long press on list items: messages, pictures, etc). I think, you mean by that `Application Bar buttons`. For example, if you want to know what buttons do in specific application, you should tap on `...`. For example, Speed dial (Phone app) has `Voicemail`, `Keypad`, `Phone book` and `Add` application bar buttons.

[image: #1]
[image: #2]